# Native Mobile App for a Rails Web App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios

How should I go about taking my `Rails 3` codebase and making a native iOS app out of it? Im not sure if it is possible to use the Rails codebase i have to build directly into an iOS app. Does my codebase need to be translated into `Objective C`? Does it make sense to use an integrated IDE like Appcelerator Titanium?

How should this be done?

Comment: You want to serve Rails application on iOS? Don't think it's possible.

Comment: Does the entire rails codebase need to be translated into `Objective C` ?

Comment: You can have it served somewhere else and communicate with it using JSON for example.

Comment: can we take our current Rails MVC framework and generate the appropriate corresponding views and controllers in `Objective C` and build to make an app very similar to the Rails web application from there?

Answer (score 1):

Well i'm sure that the best approach (if the only one?!) is using Rhodes https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes

But for sure, you cannot simply "translate" your codebase to Rhodes, but you can reuse a lot of code.